# Executing performance gap between GCC and Clang

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I have the following simple code and when I compiling them in GCC and Clang there is a huge performance difference between theirs execute times as you can see the results and the versions of the compilers below.

```c
char* strchr_x(register const char* s, int c) {
  do {
    if (*s == c) {
      return (char*)s;
    }
  } while (*s++);

  return 0;
}
```

```c
char* get(char* value, const char separator) {
  int separator_index = strchr(value, separator) - value;
  char* result = malloc(separator_index);
  memcpy(result, value, separator_index);
  result[separator_index] = '\0';

  return result;
}
```

```c
int main() {
  const char separator = ',';
  clock_t t = clock();

  for (size_t i = 0; i < 100000000; ++i) {
    free(get("127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2:1111", separator));
  }

  float elapsed_seconds = (((double)(clock() - t)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
  printf("%f seconds.\n", elapsed_seconds);

  return 0;
}
```

```
gcc version 8.1.0 (Ubuntu 8.1.0-5ubuntu1~16.04)
# gcc main.c -O3 -o gcc-main
# 1.968750 seconds.

clang version 3.8.0-2ubuntu4 (tags/RELEASE_380/final)
# clang main.c -O3 -o clang-main
# 0.000000 seconds.
```

Additionally, the 'strchr_x' implementation is exactly the same with original GCC implementation. You can see it at https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libiberty/strchr.c

When I use the 'strchr' method in the standard library; GCC's run time reducing to 0.015625 seconds.

So, my questions are:

1. Why there is huge performace difference between my 'strchr_x' and the standard library's 'strchr' in GCC?
2. Why there is this huge performace gap between in GCC and Clang?

Comment: Apparently clang optimizes out the /\* no effect \*/ for loop. Look at disassembly.

Comment: When the time is zero, it means that the compiler completely optimized out the code that you were trying to test. It can do that because the code doesn't have any observable effect.

Comment: You have undefined behavior (writing past the end of `result`). It probably isn't what causes the performance difference though.

Comment: gcc reduces the loop to `for(unsigned long x=10000000;x!=0;--x);` and then fails to remove this empty loop. Please file a bug report in gcc's bugzilla. Adding `__attribute__((flatten))` on main so inlining happens earlier lets gcc optimize, but it really should be able to do it without cheating.

Answer (score 3):

If you take your code and plug it into https://godbolt.org/ you can see that Clang will optimize away the entire for loop, which explains why it executes in 0 seconds. It likely does that because the only side effect of get is a malloc, and the result is freed immediately.

EDIT:
GCC really doesn't do too well with your code it seems...
I have checked the generated assembler again, and it's not just that it fails to remove the empty for loop (for strchr()), but it **also** fails to remove the function calls in the body of the loop (for strchr_x()).

So in the end it all boils down to some pretty strange optimization behavior, and your slowest example is actually the only one that does anything at all. I don't know ***why*** GCC fails so hard on your example, but i definitely agree that you should file this as a bug (maybe even two separate bugs, since it already fails hard when using strchr(), and even harder when using strchr_x(), even though both should be identical)

Comment: Actually, I wondered if this is a bug on the GCC side, but @marc-glisse already answered that question. Could you answer the my first question as well @felix-g?

Comment: I have checked the assembler again, and extended my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

It seems `gcc` is unable to remove the loop even though it removed the call inside the loop. Here is the link to godbolt with the code mentioned: 
https://godbolt.org/z/5wamhm

```
main:
        push    rbx
        call    clock
        mov     rbx, rax
        mov     eax, 100000000
.L5:
        sub     rax, 1 // <<-------- loop which does nothing.
        jne     .L5
        call    clock
```

This is definitely worth filing bug in gcc bugzilla. I file the bug here:
https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=92638

Answer (score -2):

Short answer on question two- `clang` (LLVM) has better code and link optimization during runtime.

Now, I'll bring up one example from experience first. The project suit that I work on required testing on raspberry pi-3 devices. When I compiled with `clang++`, it took about 15 minutes, and when with `gcc`, after more that 40 minutes of long awaiting compilation, right at the very end during linking, the build simply ran out of memory! Why? again, `clang` offers better compile time code optimization and background linking.

However, this DEPENDS, you may not get the same difference at different Ox level (try out with O2 and you'll see). For more reference I think these two articles provide some detailed explanation.

https://medium.com/@alitech_2017/gcc-vs-clang-llvm-an-in-depth-comparison-of-c-c-compilers-899ede2be378

https://clang.llvm.org/comparison.html